# getting names subgroups

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I am working  with the new version of boost 1.42 and I want to use regex with named sub groups. Below an example.

```
std::string line("match this here FIELD=VALUE in the middle");
boost::regex rgx("FIELD=(?<VAL>\\w+)", boost::regex::perl );
boost::smatch thisMatch;
boost::regex_search( line, thisMatch, rgx );
```

Do you know how to get the content of the match ?
The traditional way is

```
std::string result( mtch[1].first, mtch[1].second );
```

but **i don't** want to use this way.

I want to use the name of the subgroups as usual in Perl and in regex in general.
I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
std::string result( mtch["VAL"].first, mtch["VAL"].second );
```

Do you know how to get the value using the name of the subgroup?

Thanks
AFG

Comment: What's the difference between the way you want and the way you don't want? The statements are exactly the same.

Comment: You are right. I have just changed the code in the sample

Comment: Hi again! Have a look below 'cos I found what I needed!
Have a nice week end!

Comment: +1 'cause this just helped me correct a stupid error from Python regexes in C++: Named groups in Python are with `(?P<name>...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such option. See [Understanding Marked Sub-Expressions and Captures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html) and in particular the table on Perl and Boost.Regex equivalence. You will need to use the `boost::match_results<IteratorType>` to access any and all matches.

Comment: Hi dirkgently! I thank you for the URL. I found the solution, please see what I wrote below!
Have a nice week end!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what I want to achieve.

```
std::cout << mtch["VAL"] << std::endl;
```

I tried and it will work without any problems.

I think that is a feature available only since version 1.42 of boost, but I am not sure.